# Positive probability that $X_1+...+X_n>2n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The following one is an example I was trying to construct to check whether a result holds or not; if I am correct Borel-Cantelli should not apply, and the answer should be negative..

$\bullet$ Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F},\mathrm{P})$ and such that $X_n=n$ with probability $1/n$ and $0$ otherwise. Is it true that
$$
\mathrm{P}\left\{\omega \in \Omega: \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{X_1(\omega)+\cdots+X_n(\omega)}{n}>2\right\}>0\,\,\,\,?
$$

Comment: Fix some $a>1$ and, for every $n$, consider the event $A_n$ that $X_k\ne0$ for at least one $k$ in $(a^n,a^{n+1})$. Then $(A_n)$ is independent and $P(A_n)\to1-1/a>0$ (can you show this?) hence, almost surely, the event $A_n\cap A_{n+1}\cap A_{n+2}$ holds infinitely often. On the event $A_n\cap A_{n+1}\cap A_{n+2}$, $$\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_{a^{n+3}}}{a^{n+3}}\geqslant\frac{a^n+a^{n+1}+a^{n+2}}{a^{n+3}}=\frac{1+a+a^2}{a^3}.$$ For $a>1$ small enough, the RHS is $>2$ hence the result holds. The proof can be adapted to show that $$\limsup\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}n=+\infty\quad\text{almost surely}.$$

Comment: This is really nice, good job Did